# Adding a UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController to a UITableView programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Please excuse my ignorance with this question but I'm still trying to get to grips with the basics and have been banging my head against a wall for a couple of days over this now.

I essentially have an `NSArray` that I'm using to populate a `UITableView` that I would like users to be able to search through – and which filters the results that contain characters in the search criteria, as the users types.

There are quite a few tutorials out there for hooking up `UITableViews` and `UISearchDisplayControllers` but they all use the xib file and I want to **add everything programatically**.

I have the `UITableView`, with its contents shown in a `UIView` when the user taps a button, I appear to have added the `UISearchBar` at the top of the same view, and I '*think*' I've added a `UISearchDisplayController`. However, I can't seem to get all three playing nicely.

Here's what I have so far

```
- (IBAction)createSearchList:(id)sender {

//Make the list
AAPjsonParse * makeTheFullList = [[AAPjsonParse alloc] init];    
fullListOfRecipesForTableView = [makeTheFullList generateFullListOfRecipes];
fullListForSearchResultsInTableView = fullListOfRecipesForTableView;
recipeListForTable = [fullListForSearchResultsInTableView allKeys];
recipeListForTable = [recipeListForTable sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


//Create the UITableView
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 300, 724) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;

//Add the TableView to the view
[self.searchView addSubview:tableView];

//Create a UISearchBar for the TableView

UISearchBar * searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
//Set the searchBar as the delegate
searchBar.delegate = self;
//Add the searchBar to the UITableView
[self.searchView addSubview:searchBar];

//Create the searchViewController
UISearchDisplayController * searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
//Set the dataSource for the search as self
searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
//Set the results delegate as self – this is the view that's overlaid onto the full listing view (I think?)
searchController.delegate = self;

}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [recipeListForTable count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSString * cellTitle = [recipeListForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = cellTitle;

return cell;
}
```

I've also got some stuff at the top of my implementation file to store various bits

```
{    
NSArray * recipeListForTable;
NSMutableArray * recipeListForSearch;
int selectedRecipeIndex;

NSDictionary * fullListOfRecipesForTableView;
NSMutableDictionary * fullListForSearchResultsInTableView;

UITableView * tableView;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719517/how-do-i-use-the-uisearchbar-and-uisearchdisplaycontroller)

Answer (score 1):

This code will add a searchbar to your `tableview`

```
  searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tblView.frame), 44)];
        searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
        searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
       // searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];



    searchBar.placeholder = @"What are you eating today...";
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

       [self.tblView setTableHeaderView:searchBar];
```

After adding searchbar check how to pass data and set **delegate** and **datasource**,
I would suggest you to go through this [Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/).