# How to apply a logic in UISearchBar to reload a table with new data?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Hi guys I need your help in my situation, I am working with `UISearchBar` and all the delegate method I already declared, but I don't know the logic to reload the table data with filtered array.
All the data in my table come from json.

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 ChatListCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"contactListCell"];
 if(!cell){
     cell = [[ChatListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"contactListCell"];

 }
if (issearching) {
    ChatListData *chatlistdata = [filteredContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


NSLog(@"ceel %@", cell);
ChatListData *chatlistData = [chatList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *txtName = chatlistData.name;
NSLog(@"name %@", txtName);
NSData *emojiData = [txtName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *emojiTxtName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:emojiData   encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
 cell.txtName.text = emojiTxtName;
 cell.txtTime.text = chatlistData.time;
 NSString *stringImg = @"image";
 NSString *stringVideo = @"video";
    if(![chatlistData.mime_type isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
    if ([chatlistData.mime_type rangeOfString:stringImg].location ==   NSNotFound || [chatlistData.mime_type rangeOfString:stringVideo].location == NSNotFound) {
            if ([chatlistData.mime_type rangeOfString:stringImg].location == NSNotFound) {
                cell.txtMsg.text = @"Image";
            }else if([chatlistData.mime_type rangeOfString:stringVideo].location == NSNotFound){
                cell.txtMsg.text = @"Video";
            }
```

This is my tabview code of cell index.

```
   -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange: (NSString*)text
 {
if(text.length == 0)
{
    issearching = FALSE;
}
else
{
    NSMutableArray *chatlitdata;
    issearching= true;
    NSLog(@"searching");
    filteredContentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    filteredContentList = chatlitdata;


       // if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredContentList addObject:chatList];
        }

}
```

Comment: where you struck my bro...

Comment: Thanks sir for your response, i have a uitablview with contacts all the contacts are come from the server, now i am working with uisearchbar and i am declared all delegates method, but i don't know how will i reload table when i texting in uisearch bar. i need to search by the names of contacts.

Comment: simple , before see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719517/how-do-i-use-the-uisearchbar-and-uisearchdisplaycontroller, if you not get the answer reply here I will help you

Comment: add '[tableview reloadData]' in the end of 'searchBar textDidChange:'

Comment: ok sir @Anbu.Karthik i tried to work on your link and i will back to you sir, i always thankful to you sir

Comment: thanx bro , simply say karthik don't say sir...

Comment: hi sir i am getting this error after crash the app when i text something in searchable :- "2015-12-16 10:43:49.064 Wazapper[571:18940] -[ChatListData compare:options:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b943c60
2015-12-16 10:43:49.171 Wazapper[571:18940] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ChatListData compare:options:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b943c60'
"

Comment: hello sir i need your help, i am getting problem one of my situation.